# Deploy to run@cloud keeping the application in stopped state

Tags: cloudbees

I have some applications deployed to run@cloud that are in the stopped state. Is it possible to upgrade these applications with bees:deploy keeping them in stopped state?

This would be great so that I can decide later on when I want to apply bees:start to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I think the act of deploying would put them in the start state - but you can immediately stop them after that (ie they would only be running for a few seconds).